# Linux forensics- How can I extract sysfs procfs from a raw image?

Tags: linux, forensics

I'm developing a software that extracts files from a Linux raw image (dd).
I use SluethKit to get the partitions & files, however i can't find any files inside /sys & /proc folders.

I know the sysfs & procfs do not contain regular files (as they are loaded to the kernel), but i need to "extract" them somehow...

Any idea how can it be done for forensics (withou mount)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't. Those are virtual filesystems that don't correspond to anything on disk. They're just file-based interfaces to inside the kernel, and only ever exist on-the-fly in RAM.

Comment: You mean that all the data in those file systems is only created on startup? :0

Comment: @Reginiano Yes, exactly.

Comment: Wow, fascinating!

Comment: Not even at startup, actually. The data in those filesystem is generated _on access_. That's how it can reflect the status of the system in real time.